# Encounter random SQLiteException of "no such table"

Tags: android, database

Strange exception raise randomly (not in specific scenario/pattern), exception is as below which gives `"Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Courses: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Courses"`

Every time it runs perfectly but some times it throw above exception, so it is clear that Database is always there and table is also inside that Database.

[logcat output](http://pastebin.com/M84gHf1b)

Below relevant logcat ouput

```
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nobel.biocare/com.nobel.biocare.Courses_Events}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Courses: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Courses
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Courses: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Courses
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1235)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1189)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1271)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at com.nobel.biocare.database.DBHelper.read_Courses(DBHelper.java:444)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at com.nobel.biocare.Courses_Events.onResume(Courses_Events.java:131)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
11-29 01:16:02.570: E/AndroidRuntime(13916):    ... 12 more
```

[DBHelper class](http://pastebin.com/u0Vr37Bk)

Below relevant code snippet of DBHelper class

```
public Cursor read_Courses(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    return db.query(TBL_Courses, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

[Activity class where this exception occur](http://pastebin.com/Mc2at369)

Below relevant code snippet of activity

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyOpenDB();
    setTab_Images(Common.Courses_Events);

    if (!myApp.checkNetworkRechability()) {
        Show_No_Internet();
    }

    if (is_DB_DBHelper_Null() && isDBOpen()) {
        fetch_Courses_from_DB(dbHelper.read_Courses(MyDb));
        fetch_Events_from_DB(dbHelper.read_Events(MyDb));
    }

}
```

I am clueless about how to solve this exception.

Comment: Do you actually create the table somewhere?

Comment: i make database and all tables from SQLite extension of Firefox and import that file in my project directly, so no code for table creation.

Comment: The MyOpenDB(); method looks really fishy. Couldn't you have opened the database by calling a method on the same instance instead of reinstantiating the field? Much like you did the MyCloseDB(); method? There might be a brief moment when an instance isn't garbage collected yet and you're using the wrong reference.

Comment: @mango even i also close it every time when activity get pause, and open when it get resumed

Comment: but you can open the *same* instance with `getWritableDatabase();` furthermore, why do you have all your db methods split up. and why do you close your database in onPause instead of after loading your objects.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this method is giving exception because

return db.query(TBL_Courses, null, null, null, null, null, null);

You are not passing the column values na!!

the query should be like

return db.query(TBL_Courses, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

Where allColumns is
    private String[] allColumns = { DB.column_name,
             DB.column_name1, DB.column_name1, DB.column_name2,DB.column_name3 };

As the columns are not getting passed its showing that error.

Comment: `null` just means `*` as mentioned in the  [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: +1 for zapl, Priety if that was the case which you mention then why most of the time my code works ?? think

Answer (score 0):

> so it is clear that Database is always there

Agree, the error should be a different one.

> ...and table is also inside that Database.

No. SQLite does not lie. `no such table` means that this connection, at that point in time, was not able to see a table with that name.

Some reasons for that could be

- a bug in your database creation that sometimes does not create that table, uses a different name, or deletes the table
- you look in the wrong database
- you use the database concurrently from multiple threads and the creation was no finished yet.

Having a look at your code: Your DBHelper has that `createDatabaseFile` method that is nowhere called. Instead you use the `MyOpenDB` method which does `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(.... SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY)` which creates an empty database. I don't see how that would work at all. You have to use the code that create the database :)

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper is a small library that looks like it's doing it right. The other asset db examples on the internet all abuse `SQLiteOpenHelper` in a way that is IMO not safe.

Comment: you are right that i did not called createDatabaseFile() in java file provided by me , but in my application almost all activity use database so in first activity only i called "createDatabaseFile()" function.

Comment: i looked at your 3 reasons : no scope for second reason because only one db is there, 3rd reason will be main cause of this kind of error i think. any suggestion for how to cope with 3rd reason